# JSONiq with Zorba HMAC

Tags: zorba, jsoniq

I'm running the following code using the `fcavalieri/zorba` docker image. `hmac:compute("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "key" ,"SHA256")` produces: `97yD9DBThCSxMpjmqm+xQ+9NWaFJRhdZl0edvC0aPNg=` which when base64 decoded returns garbage rather than the expected `f7bc83f430538424b13298e6aa6fb143ef4d59a14946175997479dbc2d1a3cd8`

Am I using this module correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the output is base64, which is consistent with the [signature](http://www.zorba.io/documentation/latest/modules/zorba/cryptography/hmac) of `hmac:compute`.

I assume that you attempted to use [base64:decode](http://www.zorba.io/documentation/latest/modules/zorba/data-converters/base64) -- however, this function converts the actual base64-encoded bits to a string, interpreting them as UTF-8, which is not what you need here.

There are two binary types in JSONiq (they actually come from XML Schema): `hexBinary` and `base64Binary`. They have the same value space, but use different lexical spaces. The output can be converted to `hexBinary` so as to get hexadecimal output like so:

```
import module namespace hmac = "http://zorba.io/modules/hmac";

hexBinary(hmac:compute("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "key" ,"SHA256"))
```

Zorba then outputs the expected `F7BC83F430538424B13298E6AA6FB143EF4D59A14946175997479DBC2D1A3CD8`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much.